# When archiving in xcode a error pops up

Tags: xcode, xcode4.4

So i am Just about to upload me app the the app store. I archive my project and BAM i get this

```
Validate /Users/Kylegreenlaw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KiwiShirt-cwawgqvhcfaoiicuugooqpycmxoa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KiwiShirt1/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/KiwiShirt.app
cd /Users/Kylegreenlaw/Documents/KiwiShirt1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Applications/Xcode45-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/Kylegreenlaw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KiwiShirt-cwawgqvhcfaoiicuugooqpycmxoa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KiwiShirt1/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/KiwiShirt.app

Executable=/Users/Kylegreenlaw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KiwiShirt-cwawgqvhcfaoiicuugooqpycmxoa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KiwiShirt1/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/KiwiShirt.app/KiwiShirtcodesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation/Users/Kylegreenlaw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KiwiShirt-cwawgqvhcfaoiicuugooqpycmxoa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KiwiShirt1/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/KiwiShirt.app: valid on disk/Users/Kylegreenlaw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KiwiShirt-cwawgqvhcfaoiicuugooqpycmxoa/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KiwiShirt1/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/KiwiShirt.app: satisfies its Designated Requirementtest-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1) - (null

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

It doesn't make any sense, I have the disdrabution profile and the devlopment profile in my keychain?

What is wrong here, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check two thing:

1. Check that the Distribution/Release profile is corrected in Build settings for Target and Project.
2. Check the Scheme, of the project, and set the Archive for your Distribution/Release profile.

Comment: SIR YOU JUST FIXED MY WHOLE PROBLEM< I CAN YOU PUT IT ON THE APP STORE BECAUSE OF YOU!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!